# topmost tick in y-axis missing tick value in d3js

Tags: d3.js

You can see below, both Y-axis topmost tick (left and right) does not have visible tick value. On the left the topmost tick should be 30 and on the right it should say 450.00

Below code:

```
//Line graphs scale  
var y0 = d3.scale.linear().range([this.height, 0]);
var y1 = d3.scale.linear().range([this.height, 0]);

y0.domain([0, d3.max(graphData, function(d) {
    return Math.max(d.price) + 10;
})]);
y1.domain([0, d3.max(graphData, function(d) {
    return Math.max(d.quantity) + 1;
})]);

var yAxisRight = d3.svg.axis()
     .scale(y0)
     .orient("right").ticks(10)
     .tickFormat(function(d) { return '£'+d+'.00'; });
            
var yAxisLeft = d3.svg.axis()
     .scale(y1)
     .orient("left")
     .ticks(10);

group.append("g")
     .attr("class", "y axis")
     .style("fill", "#000")
     .call(yAxisLeft);

group.append("g")
     .attr("class", "y axis")
     .attr("transform", "translate(" + that.width + " ,0)")
     .style("fill", "#000")
     .call(yAxisRight);
```

[image]

Comment: That's by design: it's not really a tick, that's just a part of the domain path. If you do `axis.tickSizeOuter(0)` you'll see it disappear (that's for new D3 versions, I cannot remember how it is for v3, the version you're using, which was released **9 years ago**).

Comment: @GerardoFurtado It looks off. It can be fixed, I have other bar charts which look fine.. I want the 25 to move to the top or I want it to fill with next value.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider adding `.nice()` to your y-scales. From the [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#continuous_nice):

> Extends the domain so that it starts and ends on nice round values.

Currently, the max value for one scale might be 29 and the max value for the other scale might be 445, for example. 30 and 450 are outside of the domains for these scales, so you don't get tick values for them. `.nice()` will make the domains go up to 30 and 450, so you will get tick marks for them.